# Add two columns on basis of another column effective and reuse it

Tags: mysql

```
id  discount    ref_name    ref_type
101 12          Sid         national
104 34          Buny        international
108 21          Amir        national
196 35          Sanjeev     local
232 23          Anurag      local
345 2           Abhitab     international
```

Q1. How to get the total discount by each ref_type ?

```
Expected result
national 33 (12+21)
international 36 (34+2)
local 58 (35+23)
```

My query

```
select ref_type,sum(discount) from student where ref_type ='local'  UNION ALL 
select ref_type,sum(discount) from student where ref_type ='national' UNION ALL 
select ref_type,sum(discount) from student where ref_type ='international' ;
```

Q2. Get the 3rd highest discount by totaling all discount given by individual ref type?
Ans `national 33`

Q3. Show all records which exceed 50 per?
And `local 58`

For both these, I am planning to make a table with above result query and put where condition. But I am sure the way I have opted is not the correct one and will like to know the better way to achieve my goal. I am using MySQL for executing these queries.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, so code may not be perfect. You need to utilize group by.  Hope these get you going in the right direction.

Q1

```
Create table temp1 Select ref_type, sum(discount) as 
total_discount from table group by ref_type
```

Q2

```
Create table q2 (id int auto_increment primary key, 
ref_type varchar(50), total_discount int)

Insert into q2 (ref_type, total_discount) select ref_type, 
total_discount from temp1 order by total_discount;

Select * from q2 where id=3
```

Q3

```
Select * from q2 where total_discount>50
```

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a table you can still get your results by using simple queries

For Q1

```
select ref_type,sum(discount) 
from student
group by ref_type
```

For Q2 same query but with order by and limit clause

```
select ref_type,sum(discount) 
from student
group by ref_type
order by sum(discount) desc
limit 2,1
```

For Q3 same query as Q1 but with filter on aggregated result

```
select ref_type,sum(discount) 
from student
group by ref_type
having sum(discount) > 50
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c622fc/3)

Comment: It is perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: @OPTIMUS If it solved your question you could marked it as accepted [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)